# All records of the same table reladed by a field but queried by anothe field - sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, exists, cross-apply

DB: SQLSERVER 
i've this table:

```
id-description-code
1 -fdsdfsf     -A
2 -ghggh       -A
3 -tytytyty    -B
4 -hjhjydx     -A
```

i need a query that "filtering on one id" ("2" for example) returns me all record of the same table relate by "code"

look for id=2  the result should be:

```
1 -fdsdfsf     -A
2 -ghggh       -A
4 -hjhjydx     -A
```

i wrote these two query that works:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE S2 INNER JOIN
(select * from TABLE 
  WHERE ID=2) S1
  ON S1.CODE=S2.CODE


SELECT * FROM TABLE S2
WHERE S2.CODE IN (SELECT CODE FROM  TABLE S1 WHERE  ID =2)
```

could you give me others example of query (with different operators, for example CROSS APPLY, EXIST or others) to get the same result

Comment: What's wrong with the example you have? What attempts have you made using `CROSS APPLY`, `EXIST` and "others"; why didn't they work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a strange request just looking for possible ways of returning the same information. But you seem to have skipped the easiest way. Notice how I am posting consumable data so others can just write a query? You should do this in the future.

```
declare @Something table
(
    ID int
    , description varchar(20)
    , CODE char(1)
)

insert @Something values
(1, 'fdsdfsf', 'A')
,(2, 'ghggh', 'A')
,(3, 'tytytyty', 'B')
,(4, 'hjhjydx', 'A')


select *
from @Something s
join @Something s2 on s2.CODE = s.CODE
where s.ID = 2
```

Or using CROSS APPLY

```
select *
from @Something s
cross apply (select * from @Something s2 where s2.CODE = s.CODE) x
where s.ID = 2
```

Comment: this answer has all i need. Thanks for the suggestion to use this method to expose data for the next examples.

Comment: what performance consideration about put the "where" condition where you wrote or insert "and s.ID = 2" into the inner cross apply query?

Comment: What do you mean by "performance consideration"? I can't answer the implications with something so generic. If you want to know I would suggest trying it both ways and comparing the execution plan. Also, don't be scared to [race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).

Answer (score 0):

Why make it any more complicated than it needs to be?

```
select * from sometable where code = 
(select code from sometable where id=2)
```

Comment: it is for my didactic purpose, i want find out all possible methods without care about performance and complexity. i need to exercise on these operators

Comment: Then there are infinite possibilities here.

Comment: give me them some please!

Comment: This is NOT a free code writing service. I could spend weeks writing all kinds of bizarre ways of doing this. But to what end? So you can see a bunch of stupidly complicated ways of doing something super simple?